# Pandas: Mapping various similar sub-strings to single, standard format

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe column has various format sub-strings of company names that need to be mapped to a fixed representation of the company name. These multiple formats are recorded in sotest.json:

```
{
    "ABERCOMBIEFITCH": ["A&F", "A & F", "A& F", "ABERCOMBIE & FITCH"],
    "COCACOLA": ["COKE", "COCA-COLA", "COCACOLA"]
}
```

This json is read into a df as follows:

```
with open('sotest.json') as tf:
    testdata = json.load(tf)
indexlist = []
itemslist = []
for k, v in testdata.items():
    indexlist.append(k)
    itemslist.append(v)
sojsondf = pd.DataFrame({'AssortedNames': itemslist}, index = indexlist)
```

Below is a test-df:

```
namesdf = pd.DataFrame(data = ["A&F Ltd", "A & F CO", "A& F COMPANY", "ABERCOMBIE & FITCH LIMITED", 
                               "COKE M/S", "COCA-COLA COMPANY", "COCACOLA BOTTLING CO", "SONY"], 
                      columns = ['RecordedCompanyName'])
```

And the following function is applied to above df column to get standardised output:

```
def sorowchecker(inputstring, sojsondf):
    match = False
    for i, row in sojsondf.iterrows():
        if any(sponsor in inputstring for sponsor in row['AssortedNames']):
            match = True
            if match == True:
                break
    return i if match == True else "DIRECTMARKETING"
```

Use of the above function:

```
   namesdf['Company'] = namesdf['RecordedCompanyName'].apply(sorowchecker, args=(sojsondf, ))
```

Actual namesdf.shape[0] ~ 60k and actual sojsondf.shape[0] ~ 50 which means the program takes quite a while. Any suggests on how sorowchecker() might be made to run faster and/or other improvements (extra kudos for anything using concurrency)? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this would help with speed - have you considered mapping through a reversed dict of sojsondf? Something like {"A&F":"ABERCROMBIEFITCH","A & F":"ABERCROMBIEFITCH" etc...} and then `namesdf['Company'] = namesdf['RecordedCompanyName'].map(sojsondict).fillna('DIRECTMARKETING')`

Comment: what would be the desired output with your example?

Comment: @SebastienD: you can run the program and find out if you can't follow the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you don't need to create the new dataframe, just use the dict to create an inverse dict and `map`:

```
with open('sotest.json') as tf:
    testdata = json.load(tf)

backward = {x:k for k,v in testdata.items() for x in v}

# pattern to check if any key in the names
pattern = '|'.join(backward.keys())

# output:    
(namesdf['RecordedCompanyName']
 .str.extract(f'({pattern})')[0]   # extract the first match key
 .map(backward)                    # convert the match key to actual name
 .fillna('DIRECTMARKETING')        # replace the none-match with default
)
```

Output:

```
0    ABERCOMBIEFITCH
1    ABERCOMBIEFITCH
2    ABERCOMBIEFITCH
3    ABERCOMBIEFITCH
4           COCACOLA
5           COCACOLA
6           COCACOLA
7    DIRECTMARKETING
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: `extract`! exactly the function I was missing in my answer. Using `split` to get the matched part felt so wrong to me. Awesome stuff 

Answer (score 1):

I used `testdata` to pre-compile regex, then use them in `replace` to replace them with the "canonical" name, and use `map` to only get the replaced part.

after that, every row with a `'Company'` not from the list, gets replaced with `'DIRECTMARKETING`.

can you see if this work for you?

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

testdata = {
    "ABERCOMBIEFITCH": ["A&F", "A & F", "A& F", "ABERCOMBIE & FITCH"],
    "COCACOLA": ["COKE", "COCA-COLA", "COCACOLA"]
}

namesdf = pd.DataFrame(data=["A&F Ltd", "A & F CO", "A& F COMPANY", "ABERCOMBIE & FITCH LIMITED",
                             "COKE M/S", "COCA-COLA COMPANY", "COCACOLA BOTTLING CO", "SONY"],
                       columns=['RecordedCompanyName'])

regex_dict = {re.compile('|'.join(v)): k for k, v in testdata.items()}

comapny_regex = re.compile('|'.join(testdata.keys()))

namesdf['Company'] = namesdf['RecordedCompanyName'].replace(regex=regex_dict).map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
namesdf.loc[~namesdf['Company'].str.contains(comapny_regex), 'Company'] = "DIRECTMARKETING"
print(namesdf)
```

Output:

```
          RecordedCompanyName          Company
0                     A&F Ltd  ABERCOMBIEFITCH
1                    A & F CO  ABERCOMBIEFITCH
2                A& F COMPANY  ABERCOMBIEFITCH
3  ABERCOMBIE & FITCH LIMITED  ABERCOMBIEFITCH
4                    COKE M/S         COCACOLA
5           COCA-COLA COMPANY         COCACOLA
6        COCACOLA BOTTLING CO         COCACOLA
7                        SONY  DIRECTMARKETING
```

Comment: Sony is not in the json, so should be output as 'DIRECTMARKETING'

Comment: @shanlodh correct, that should be simple enough, I'll add some steps, thanks for pointing it out